# Viewing package documentation

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to view a package's top level documentation in R?  Currently, if I'd like to view the package documentation for the stringr package I'll do something like:

```
?str_replace
```

...and then navigate to the bottom of the package and click the "index" hyperlink.  Is there a way to just go straight to the index page for stringr?

Comment: `library(help="stringr")`?

Comment: `help(package = 'stringr')` will open up the index page directly.